# KeePass - Multiples passwords for the same entry

Tags: windows-8.1, keepass

I would like to know if it's possible to add two different passwords to the same entry and have KeePass ask me which one I want to use. I have an internet service which requires me to have two different passwords in order to use it and having KeePass only store one of them is impractical.

I've been going through the options but I can't seem to find a way to do this, if there is one.

Thanks for the support in advance.

Comment: Can you add the same entry twice? That way it'd have to ask which 'version' of the /site/password you'd like to use.

Comment: Sorry to answer now, but that indeed solved it. Somestimes we think of too complex ways, when there's a simpler way to reach the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

- Create one entry for the first password, filling title, username, password, and URL
- Duplicate that entry, editing the title to say it's the second password (like appending `#2`to the title), and set the password.